# Tkinter: destroying widgets does not clear memory

Tags: python, tkinter, memory, widget, destroy

I have the following tkinter code in which a button updates (delete and display again) a graph. This occurs by destroying the widgets in the bottom frame (the graph) and displaying the graph again.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import numpy as np

class Main_Program(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        
        self.geometry("500x500")
        
        # ---------------------------------------- TOP FRAME (Button)
        
        self.top_frame = tk.Frame(self)  
        ttk.Button(self.top_frame,text="Update graph",command=self.update_graph).pack()
        self.top_frame.pack()
        
        # ---------------------------------------- BOTTOM FRAME (Graph)
        
        self.bottom_frame = tk.Frame(self) 
         
        DisplayGraph(self.bottom_frame,
        x_limit= (-10, 10) ,
        delta_x= 0.1 ,
        y_input= "2*x+2" )
        
        self.bottom_frame.pack() 
        
    
    def update_graph(self):
        
        # ----------------------------- DESTROY THE FRAME
        
        for widget in self.bottom_frame.winfo_children():
            widget.destroy()
        
        #  ----------------------------- DISPLAY NEW GRAPH
        
        DisplayGraph(self.bottom_frame,
        x_limit= (-10, 10) ,
        delta_x= 0.1 ,
        y_input= "2*x+2" )
        
class DisplayGraph:
    def __init__(self,passed_frame,
                x_limit=(), # TUPLE (-10,10)
                delta_x=0.0, # FLOAT 0.1
                y_input='', # STRING 2*x+2
                figsize_x=6,
                figsize_y=5):

        self.x_limit = x_limit
        self.delta_x = delta_x
        self.y_input = y_input
        
        # ---------------------------------------------------------- CREATE FIGURE AND SUBPLOT

        self.fig = Figure(figsize=(figsize_x,figsize_y),dpi=100)
        self.ax = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
        self.ax.grid()
        
        # ---------------------------------------------------------- PLOT
        
        self.plot_input()

        # ---------------------------------------------------------- PACK AND DRAW

        self.canvas_frame = tk.Frame(passed_frame,bg="black")
        self.canvas_mat = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig, master=self.canvas_frame)
        
        self.canvas_mat.get_tk_widget().pack(anchor="center", expand=True,padx=2,pady=2)
        self.canvas_frame.pack(side=tk.LEFT,anchor="center", expand=True)
        
        self.canvas_mat.draw()
        
        # ----------------------------------------------------------
        
    def plot_input(self):

        x = np.arange(self.x_limit[0],self.x_limit[1],self.delta_x)
        y = eval(self.y_input)

        self.ax.plot(x,y)

App = Main_Program()
App.mainloop()
```

When opening the Task Manager, I notice that the memory that the python script is using only increases after clicking the button several times.

Is there a way of preventing this? I don't know if this is related to garbage collection or something related to the destroy method.

I already tried using gc.collect() to clear the objects that are not referenced (maybe the destroyed widgets), but it didn't work. I also tried using .pack_forget(), which didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this happens because of the creation of multiple instances of FigureCanvasTkAgg. I don't know if they do not get properly deleted when destroying the frame. Just creating one instance of FigureCanvasTkAgg and updating (clearing and replotting) the subplots fixed my problem.

Comment: I think this is a known issue with Matplotlib, if that makes you feel any more vindicated