# I'm getting an error Out of memory in a function that plot a graph using tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Hi I have this function that plot ten points in a graph and it is called every 30000 seconds. But I'm getting an error after a while it says Out of memory and the program close. Can anybody help me?

```
 def plot(self):
    if self.plot_frame is not None:
        self.plot_frame.destroy()

    self.plot_frame = tk.Frame(self, bg=self.bg)
    self.plot_frame.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

    simulation = Simulation
    self.fig = plt.Figure()
    simulation.ax = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
    simulation.ax.set_title("Damage Accumulation Curve")
    simulation.ax.set_xlabel("Load Case")
    simulation.ax.set_ylabel("Accumulative Fatigue Damage")

    x_axis = np.arange(0, len(Simulation.accumulated) )

    x = np.array(x_axis[-10:])
    y = np.array(Simulation.accumulated[-10:])
    x = x[-10:]
    y = y[-10:]
    plt.clf()
    simulation.ax.plot(x, y)
    self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig, master=self.plot_frame)
    self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    self.canvas.draw()
    self.graph_theta.set(Simulation.theta)
    self.graph_arcl.set(Simulation.arcl)
    self.after(30000, self.plot)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74870484/tkinter-destroying-widgets-does-not-clear-memory

Comment: Reuse the ```Figure``` and ```FigureCanvasTkAgg``` instance. You need to call ```canvas.draw()``` after plotting with Matplotlib API.

Comment: @relent95 how can I reuse the Figure and FigureCanvasTkAgg? I tryied every thing but it doesn't work it doesn't plot anything

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30783010/1186624).